# Scape Selenium to Pandas - List issue

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape the rotten tomatoes site with this code but I'm getting an error:
"ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index".

I'd be grateful if someone could help me correct the issue with the index.

Many thanks for your help.

(original code from: [How to scrape more than one page of critic reviews from Rotten Tomatoes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198611/how-to-scrape-more-than-one-page-of-critic-reviews-from-rotten-tomatoes))

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# for explicit wait:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time
import pandas as pd

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/avengers_endgame/reviews")

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'review_table')))


review_1df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Reviewer', 'Website', 'Review', 'Score'])
dates = []
reviews = []
scores = []
newscores = []
names = []
sites = []


results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("review_area") # right box
reviewnum = 1

reviewers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row review_table_row']")
print(len(reviewers))

for r in results:
    dates.append(r.find_element_by_class_name('subtle').text)
    reviews.append(r.find_element_by_class_name('the_review').text)
    scores.append(r.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'small subtle review-link')]").text)
    
    for r in reviewers:
        names.append(r.find_element_by_xpath("(.//div[contains(@class,'critic_name')]/a)[1]").text)
        sites.append(r.find_element_by_xpath("(.//div[contains(@class,'critic_name')]/a)[2]").text)
        reviewnum+=1
        
for score in scores:
    if score == ('Full Review'):
        newscores.append('no score')
    else:
        score2 = score[30:]
        newscores.append(score2)

driver.quit()

review_1df['Date'] = dates
review_1df['Review'] = reviews
review_1df['Score'] = newscores
review_1df['Reviewer'] = names
review_1df['Website'] = sites
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to click the "next" button (the blue box with arrow) until the page limit is reached. At each click instance, you can use `BeautifulSoup` to extract the results:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd, re, time
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver') 
d.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/avengers_endgame/reviews')
results = []
while True:
   p = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')
   results.extend([{'date': i.select_one('div.review-date').get_text(strip=True),
                    'reviewer':i.select_one('div.critic_name a').get_text(strip=True),
                    'website':getattr(i.select_one('em.critic-publication'), 'get_text', lambda **_:None)(strip=True),
                    'review':i.select_one('div.the_review').get_text(strip=True),
                    'score':x[0] if (x:=re.findall('(?<=Original Score:\s)[\d\./]+', i.select_one('div.review_area').text)) else None}
       for i in p.select('div.row.review_table_row')])
   k1, k2 = map(int, re.findall('\d+', p.select_one('span.pageInfo').text))
   if k1 == k2:
       break
   d.execute_script('''document.querySelector('div a[data-qa="next-btn"]').click()''')
   time.sleep(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Output

```
                 date          reviewer  ...                                             review score
0       July 28, 2021    Nathan Mattise  ...  The true superteam event releases marked somet...  None
1       July 23, 2021    Robin Holabird  ...                  This goes beyond the usual scale.  None
2       July 13, 2021     Rick Marshall  ...  A film that somehow manages to be as epic as f...  None
3        May 11, 2021       Nick Levine  ...  Films don't come any huger than this: the clos...  None
4      April 29, 2021     Olly Richards  ...  There really is very little that could be impr...   5/5
..                ...               ...  ...                                                ...   ...
539    April 23, 2019  Matthew Pejkovic  ...  A grand, clever and heartfelt blockbuster sure...   4/5
540    April 23, 2019   Jason Escamilla  ...  If you're a Marvel fan, this film is made for ...  None
541    April 23, 2019     Clayton Davis  ...  Jeremy Renner's new haircut-having Hawkeye and...   3/4
542    April 23, 2019     Donald Clarke  ...  Endgame spends too much time wallowing in its ...   3/5
543  November 5, 2018        Brian Gill  ...  Endgame works very, very well as a movie, as a...  None

[544 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Hi Ajax1234
Thanks for your reply. I was hoping to find out what was the issue with my list - do you have any idea?

Your code looks good but it did not work for me. I got an invalid syntax error here: "(x:=re.....

Could you explain this part to me ?<=Original Score:\s)[\d\./]+'

Regards & thanks

Comment: @user3165601 `:=` is an assignment expression, available in versions >= Python3.8. Please see my recent edit, as I made the solution compatible with versions < 3.8